# Схема коммутации. Печатная форма

Tags: сеть, печать

Я создал модуль которая переводит такие схемы коммутации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В такую печатную форму:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И теперь нужно это описать.

- Все о коммутациии
- Актуальность коммутации

Информации об этом очень мало. Не могу ничего путного найти.

Может кто объяснить эту тему, или дадите ссылки. Хоть что-то...

Спасибо.